# Creating a bitmap from raw headers and image data

Tags: c++, bitmap

I am extremely new to manipulating bitmap data in C++, and I have a problem.  I'm trying to follow [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Example_1) example from wikipedia.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //fileheader
    BITMAPFILEHEADER* bf = new BITMAPFILEHEADER;
    bf->bfType = 66;
    bf->bfSize = 70;
    bf->bfOffBits = 54;

    //infoheader
    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bi = new BITMAPINFOHEADER;
    bi->biSize = 40;
    bi->biWidth = 2;
    bi->biHeight = 2;
    bi->biPlanes = 1;
    bi->biBitCount = 24;
    bi->biCompression = 0;
    bi->biSizeImage = 16;
    bi->biXPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    bi->biYPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    bi->biClrUsed = 0;
    bi->biClrImportant = 0;

    //image data
    unsigned char* thedata = new unsigned char;
    thedata[0] = 0;
    thedata[1] = 0;
    thedata[2] = 255;

    thedata[3] = 255;
    thedata[4] = 255;
    thedata[5] = 255;

    thedata[6] = 0;
    thedata[7] = 0;

    thedata[8] = 255;
    thedata[9] = 0;
    thedata[10] = 0;

    thedata[11] = 0;
    thedata[12] = 255;
    thedata[13] = 0;

    thedata[14] = 0;
    thedata[15] = 0;

    //dc
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);

    //bitmap info
    BITMAPINFO* bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)bi;

    //handle to bitmap
    HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBitmap(dc, bi, CBM_INIT, thedata, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    //output to bmp....?
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("outtestbmp.bmp");
    outFile << hbmp;
    outFile.close();

}
```

I've been searching Google for the past couple days trying to figure out how to get this done but I still can't seem to make it work.

This complies without errors, but the outtestbmp.bmp file in the end is unopenable.  Are there any huge mistakes I'm making (probably dozens) that are preventing this from working?  (I have high suspicions that using ofstream to output my bmp data is wrong).

**EDIT**:  I've been told that setting bftype to 66 is wrong.  What is the correct value?

Also, I've created a .bmp file of what the output should be.  Here is the hex data for that bmp:

```
42 4D 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 18        
00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF  
FF FF 00 00 FF 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00
```

and here is the data for my .bmp I'm outputting:

```
42 00 46 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 36 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 18 
00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 13 0B 00 00 13 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 
FF FF 00 00 FF 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your output e.g. by comparing the data to a known good simple bmp file with a hexeditor?

Comment: No I have not!  I'll get a Hex editor and check that now.

Comment: at least do: unsigned char* thedata = new unsigned char[16];

Comment: The correct value is given in both the wikipedia article to link to, and my answer below.

Comment: You should probably add, bf->bfReserved1 = 0 and bf->bfReserved2 = 0; When you create a new object on the heap whatever previous value was stored in that memory address will be still there (more or less).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bf->bfType == 66;
```

This is wrong on two counts. Firstly it's the wrong value (the magic value are the bytes 'BM' or 0x4d42 on a little-endian machine), and secondly it's not an assignment.

Then:

```
unsigned char* thedata = new unsigned char;
```

Only allocating *1* char?

And this:

```
outFile << hbmp;
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. You're just writing out a handle. You didn't need to create a bitmap, you just need to write out the data structures you've initialised (once you've made them correct).

And why are you new'ing everything? There's no need for this stuff to be dynamically allocated (and you're not delete'ing it either).

I would generally do it something like this (some code removed for brevity):

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
bf.bfType = 0x4d42;
bf.bfSize = 70;
bf.bfOffBits = 54;

//infoheader
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
bi.biSize = 40;
bi.biWidth = 2;
etc...

//image data
unsigned char* thedata = new unsigned char[16]; // Should really calculate this properly
thedata[0] = 0;
....

//output to bmp....?
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("outtestbmp.bmp");
outFile.write((char *)&bf,sizeof(bf));
outFile.write((char *)&bi,sizeof(bi));
outFile.write((char *)thedata, 16);
outFile.close();
```

Comment: Right, I've already fixed that haha my bad I forgot it was still there when I had copied my code.  Also if I don't add the new unsigned char I get a compile error because the pointer is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

First you don't allocate enough memory for all your pixels, it should be something along the lines of

```
unsigned char* thedata = new unsigned char[numPixels * bytesPerPixel];
```

In your case, with a `2` by `2` picture and `24 bpp` (bits per pixel), you should allocate 12 bytes.

Each pixel will correspond to three bytes in a row for their `red`, `green` and `blue` channel.

Note: I've never used Window's bitmap creation process but I worked with many libraries to manipulate images, including `FreeImage`, `SDL` and `GD`

Comment: Actually in this case you should allocate 16 bytes. The width of each row must be rounded up to a multiple of 4 bytes; since the natural row size is 2 pixels of 3 bytes each, it results in 6 bytes which must be rounded to 8. 2 rows of 8 byes is 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

HBITMAP is a handle to a bitmap not an actual bitmap. The real bitmap is stored in Kernel memory. You don't need to make any calls to the GDI if you are just writing the bitmap to a file. Even if it was an actual bitmap cout would need an operator overload to actually write the memory structure to a file since it isn't stored in memory the same it is on disk.

All you need to do is write the BITMAPFILEHEADER to a file, then write the BITMAPINFOHEADER to the file, and then write the data (if we are talking RGB, non-indexed).

Here is more info on how bitmaps are actually stored on disk.

[Bitmap Storage (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Reading a bitmap from a file is just same.

Comment: So `outFile << bf << bi << thedata;` ?

Comment: Yes, except that theData will need to be a set of RGBQUAD structures (`struct RGBQUAD { char Blue; char Green; char Red; char Reserved;}`). Please check out that link it really does a great deal to explain how Bitmaps are actually stored.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to allocate enough data for your pixels:

```
unsigned char* thedata = new unsigned char[2 * 2 * 3];
```

Then you need to use `write` and open the file as `binary`.

Instead of:

```
outFile.open("outtestbmp.bmp");
outFile << hbmp;
```

Something like:

```
outFile.open("outtestbmp.bmp", ios::binary||ios::out);

outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(bf), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(bi), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(thedata), 2 * 2 * 3); 

outfile.close();
```